# Edit Image on grid /table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a project in which i want to display name and Image of every Users with edit option where user can edit their name and image
here is my code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="panel-body no-padding">
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $mysql_database = "Dummy";
    $connect_mysql = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    $mysql_db = mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect_mysql);
    $query = mysql_query("Select * from User");
?>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="warning">                
                <th>Banner Image</th>
                <th>BannerId</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $UserID=$data['UserID'];    
?>
            <tr>                                   
               <td>
                  <?php
                       $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Dummy");
                       $sql = "SELECT Images from Users WHERE UserID='$UserID'";
                       $sth = $db->query($sql);
                       $res2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
                       echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($res2['Images']) . '" width="150px" />';
                   ?>              
              </td>
              <td><?php echo $data['BannerId'] ?></td>
              <td> <input type="file" name="file1"> </td>
              <td><div style="margin-right:20px;">
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $bannerid ?>"  class="btn-success btn" name="Update">
<!--                <a href="form1.php?Update=<?php echo $UserID?>"><button class="btn-success btn">ADD</button></a> &nbsp;-->
<!--                <a href="form1.php?delete=<?php echo $UserID?>"> <button class="btn-success btn">DELETE</button></a></div></td>   -->
           </tr>
           <?php }?>    
        </tbody>
    </table>                           
 </div>
 </form>
```

This code is working for last user only when I try to edit other users it is giving me **unsupported File Format**

please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
               <div class="panel-body no-padding">
                <?php
                $hostname = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $mysql_database = "Dummy";
                $connect_mysql = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
                $db = mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect_mysql);
                $query = mysql_query("Select * from User");
                ?>
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="warning">

                                <th>Banner Image</th>
                                <th>BannerId</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                        $UserID=$data['UserID'];
                        $bannerid=$data['BannerId'];
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <?php
                                $sql = "SELECT Images from Users WHERE UserID='$UserID'";
                                $sth = $db->query($sql);
                                $res2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
                                ?>
                                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,base64_encode(<?echo $res2['Images'];?>)" width="150px" />
                                </td>
                                <td><?php echo $bannerid;?></td>
                                <td><input type="file" name="file1"> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div style="margin-right:20px;">
                                            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $bannerid;?>"  class="btn-success btn" name="Update">
                                    </div>
                                </td>    
                           </tr>
                        <?}?>   
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </form>
```